# Different view.phtml files for group & bundle product types in magento

Tags: magento

Im trying to make some design changes to group, bundle and configurable product types on the product page itself. So far Ive been doing this with assigning different templates to products, but at this moment this is not an option unfortunately...

I have already designed the custom_view.phtml and custom_view2.phtml for bundle and group type products, but I dont know how to make magento to render those phtml files according to those product types...

can anyone help me with this issue please?

Thank you...

Answer (score 9):

I know this topic is somewhat old, but I found myself needing an answer for this question also, and this is what worked for me:

in bundle.xml, find

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle translate="label" module="bundle">
```

and add the following reference:

```
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method='setTemplate'><template>path/to/your/template/view.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Look in /app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/catalog.xml

There are lines like the following:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped translate="label" module="catalog>
  ...
</PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
```

In that XML you can add layout xml to override the template used. You should copy this layout xml file into your own skin and make the changes there. I am guessing you want:

```
<reference name="content">
  <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="path/to/your/custom_view2.phtml">
</reference>
```

Comment: Hello Tim. Thanks for help. I found that code and I will be using it according to my needs. However, I cant see any code related to BUNDLE products. Can I just copy this and change it to "Product_Type_Bundle" ? Will it work this way ? 

Thank you...

Comment: Don't do it there. Do it in local.xml in your theme's layout folder. You can merge in the changes for the bundle product type from bundle.xml.

Comment: Hi @Ben thanks for response. Im a bit confused with the code, can you give me an example code how can I implement it as for the bundled products please? Thank you...

Comment: I was not able to render bundled or configurable products with the code that you provided @Tim  its still rendering with default view.phtml I did delete ALL the cache from back end and in my browsers but still the same...

Any ideas please? Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I've done for configurable check it please,

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Configurable)</label>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>catalog/product/configurableview.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```